# ¿Cómo cambiar nombre de variables nominales de un gráfico de barra?

Tags: r

Con el siguiente código obtuve un diagrama de barra que muestra: carreras(sus códigos) y sexo (0:varón, 1: mujer). La leyenda muestra sexo.

```
ingresantes <- read_excel("D:/PRUEBAS en R/Ingresantes_2015_USAR_R.xlsx")

# Eliminar los valores ausentes de la tabla
ingresantes<-na.omit(ingresantes)

#library(tidyverse)
ingresantes %>% 
group_by(Carrera_Codigo, Sexo) %>% 
count() -> conteos
conteos

ggplot(data = conteos, aes(x = Carrera_Codigo, y = n, fill = Sexo)) +   
geom_col()
```

Como la variable Sexo, toma los valores 0:varón y 1: mujer y los códigos de carrera son números del 1 al 22, la gráfica me muestra obviamente en la leyenda los números 0 y 1 para Sexo y lo mismo en la abscisa. Cómo puedo cambiar Sexo por "Varón", "Mujer" y los códigos de las carreras por sus nombres??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que partimos de una `data.frame` parecido a esto:

```
ingresantes <- data.frame(Carrera_Codigo = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                          Sexo = sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE))

ingresantes

   Carrera_Codigo Sexo
1               1    2
2               3    1
3               1    2
4               2    1
5               2    1
6               2    2
7               3    2
8               1    2
9               2    2
10              3    2
```

Lo que buscas hacer es "recodificar" los valores con las etiquetas apropiadas, puedes hacerlo, simplemente creando una variable del tipo `factor` y estableciendo las etiquetas en el orden de cada valor:

```
ingresantes$Carrera_Codigo <- factor(ingresantes$Carrera_Codigo, labels=c("Matemática", "Lengua", "Geografía"))
ingresantes$Sexo <- factor(ingresantes$Sexo, labels=c("Femenino","Masculino"))
ingresantes

   Carrera_Codigo      Sexo
1      Matemática Masculino
2       Geografía  Femenino
3      Matemática Masculino
4          Lengua  Femenino
5          Lengua  Femenino
6          Lengua Masculino
7       Geografía Masculino
8      Matemática Masculino
9          Lengua Masculino
10      Geografía Masculino
```

El código de la gráfica no necesita ningún cambio en particular.

Comment: Muuuchaas gracias! :)